# In Intellij, how can I get a List on the left hand side when I extract a variable that's an ArrayList?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring

As an example, if I extract a variable from this:

```
return new ArrayList<CrudTestData<Foo>>();
```

It will turn the code into this:

```
ArrayList<CrudTestData<Foo>> list = new ArrayList<CrudTestData<Foo>>();
return list;
```

How can I automatically get a list on the left hand side like this?

```
List<CrudTestData<Foo>> list = new ArrayList<CrudTestData<Foo>>();
return list;
```

Theoretically, Intellij should know to use a `List` instead of a `Collection` because the method returns a `List`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Mac, it's shift-tab to go from editing the variable name to the type, and then you can use arrows to select the type you want. The dropdown that shows up when you first extract the variable should show you the binding:

[image]

... and then...

[image]

Comment: Wow that's esoteric.  I'm on a PC and for some reason it doesn't say that.  "It says, `Ctrl+Alt+V` to reassign existing variable". But that key combination still did it.  Weird to me how Shift-tab does not work in a normal variable rename though.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh, I'll edit my answer to reflect that I'm on a Mac. Should have thought of that! To be honest, the shortcut I use is just "<home> <forward-delete><forward-delete><forward-delete><forward-delete><forward-delete>" ;)